# Vue TypeScript cannot find module

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Who can help me? I have this `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./backend/app/*"]
    },
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "include": ["backend/app/**/*.ts", "backend/app/**/*.vue"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

And inside my `main.ts` file which lives inside `backend/app/main.ts` I am importing this `import app from './app.vue';` located in `backend/app/app.vue` and this file only contains:

```
<template>
  <router-view/>
</template>
```

And when I compile, TS throws this error

> TS2307: Cannot find module './app.vue' or its corresponding type declarations

I also use webpack and I provided `ts-loader`:

```
{
        test: /\.ts?$/u,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/u,
        options: {
          appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/u],
        },
},
```

Project compiles correctly and works, but TS throws this.

Comment: Try import path "@/app.vue"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix is to declare `shims-vue.d.ts`

```
declare module '*.vue' {
  import Vue from 'vue';
  export default Vue;
}
```